# what is the problem on this pages?

Tags: php

i have some pages in folder called (pages)

if i open the main page that called index.php

and click on main page in the navbar the index.php not found
and when i clicked on contact us double clicks  that also not found page

what can i do to fixed this files ?
 i attached files

http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?939lpvll8tshzl7

Comment: No one is going to download 1.5MB. Extract the relevant code and paste it here.

Comment: i dont need to do that i just want to know where the problem in this code?

Comment: -1 for unwillingness to do any work to identify the problem himself, and an expectation that people here will willingly do all the debugging work for him

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably going to regret having spent time looking at this dump of the entire website, and it doesn't help that the page is in arabic? (which I don't speak or read)

In pages/header.php you have the following html for lines 41-46:

```
<li>
    <a href="page.html"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">ãßÊÈÉ ÇáÝíÏíæ</span></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="page.html"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">ãÚÑÖ ÇáÕæÑ</span></a>
</li>
```

The anchor tag href is explicitly set to page.html, so when you click on those links, the browser will send a request for page.html in the root folder of the site. This page.html does not exist.

On line 63, you have:

```
<a href="../index.php#"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">ÇáÑÆíÓíÉ</span></a>
```

change this from ../index.php# to ./index.php#

You seem to have problems with your url paths.

Comment: +1 for being willing to help when no one else (including myself) had the patience...